# How to Display column names using PDO::FETCH_COLUMN with index?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

//PHP code for submit

```
include("cfg.php");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){

$tbname = $_POST['c'];
$last = $_POST['dbTables'];

$result = $db->prepare("ALTER TABLE `cont` ADD $tbname DECIMAL(20,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00' AFTER $last");
$result->execute(); 
unset($_POST);
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

//BODY

```
<form name="f1" method="post" action="">
<table>
<tr><td>Last Column<td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select id="dbTables" name="dbTables">

<?PHP
    $rs = $db->query('DESCRIBE cont');
    $rs->execute();

    $table_fields = $rs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    foreach ($table_fields as $row){


        echo '<option value="'.$row.'" selected="selected">'.$row.'</option>';


    }
?>


</select>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="c" placeholder="db table name"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<table name="tb3">

<th>Date</th>
<th>Alobs</th>
<th>Claimant</th>
<th>Description</th>
<?PHP

$result= $db->query('DESCRIBE cont');
$result->execute();

$fieldname = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
foreach($fieldname as $row){

    echo '<th>'.$row.'</th>';
}


?>


</table>
```

Guys is there a way to exclude displaying the ones with yellow highlight? I've been searching for an answer in the net but to no avail. Hope someone helps. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EJVC.png

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Comment: If you're altering the schema to add a column to a table each time you submit data that's usually a sign of a massive problem, like violateing the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You should already have a schema that can accommodate whatever data you're saving prior to that method being called, that's just how it's done.

Comment: If you need a more abstract way of storing data there's ways of using key-value type table structures or serializing data into a JSON type column where you can create arbitrary fields as necessary.